# image overlap on the text while scale onscroll using TweenMax

Tags: html, css, scaling, gsap

I'm new in HTML programming and my main idea is to make text move out of the way while TweenMax animate(scale image)

I Have a function to enlarge and reverse image in position, but then scroll image are overlaping text.

This is a default image and text position :

[image]

But then i scroll on start(like green thing on screenshot bellow) screenshot are overlaping the text:

[image]

I want to make it so when the picture is enlarged it would push the text down and not overlap over it. What should I use in this case? I can give an example of my current code if needed. I did some research and either this is so easy with something like CSS that there are no examples or it is impossible to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just give that text's main parent div below css, and don't use scale for that, just use width:100%; you can achieve it.

```
div {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```